# Decorator's return is different from the actual return

Tags: python, time, decorator, python-decorators

##### Code

Why I am getting different results?

```py
from time import time
def speed_test(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time() - start
        print(f"Execution time is: {end:.17f}s  # Decorator")
    return wrapper
@speed_test 
def sorting(L):
    L.sort() # For example
    
def sorting_1(L1):
    L1.sort()
    
T = [10, 5, 3, 1, 0]
L = T.copy()

sorting(T)

a = time()
sorting_1(L)
b = time() - a
print(f"Execution time is: {b:.17f}s  # Main")
```

##### Expected output

```
Execution time is: 0.00000977516174316s  # Decorator
Execution time is: 0.00000977516174316s  # Main
```

##### My output

```
Execution time is: 0.00000977516174316s  # Decorator
Execution time is: 0.00000572204589844s  # Main
```

Why those two results are different?
Why they are not the same?

Comment: Printing stuff takes time.

Comment: Just a note, `time.perf_counter` is more accurate than `time.time`, especially in cases like these where the total execution time is sub-millisecond. I ran your code and the execution time displayed is 0 seconds unless I magnify the list by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: @user2357112 where did he include `print` in the time measurement?

Comment: @no_hex: `b` isn't computed until `wrapper` finishes printing.

Comment: @user2357112 You're correct I've missed it completely. :)

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry I get wrong writing the question. Can you check what is the problem right now? And can you tell me which one I should I use, Decorator or normal?

Comment: The lookup procedure for `func` in the definition of `wrapper` is different from the lookup procedure for `sorting_1`.

Comment: @chepner Can you explain it more clearly please?

Comment: `sorting_1` is a global name; `func` is part of a closure.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but generally the wrapper returned by a decorator should return the return value of the wrapped function. Yours returns `None`. It works in your case because your decorated functions don't return anything either, but it'll break as soon as you use that decorator with a function that does return something.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would say here:

1. `time.perf_counter` is more efficient for things like this
2. [A guess] In python, decorated functions "replace" the original function in the call stack, so they might be slower for that reason.